# php $_GET empty

Tags: php, jquery

so i have tried to find an answer to my problem but with no result.

main.js

```
$.ajax ({
    method: "POST",
    url:"main_d.php",
    data: {type : 4}
})
.done(function(msg_info) {
    $('#info_id').append(msg_info)
})
```

main_d.php

```
<?php
$tipe = $_POST['type'];

switch($tipe) {
    case 4:
        info_add();
    break;
}

function info_add() {
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $item_nr = $_GET['id'];
        echo $item_nr;
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}
?>
```

so this is my small code that i have tried to use but with no result....i only get ERROR out. if i use var dump i get Array(0) {}
the url has the ?ID=1
i get the URL from the the main_d.php from a php code

```
"<a href=info.html?id=" . $id . " target=_blank>CLICK HERE</a>"
```

Comment: What? Your AJAX has no GET params...

Comment: URL doesn't have any `id` as query string.

Comment: you cant use GET method when you call the function internally. Only way to use pass the variable value to that function like info_add($id)

Comment: You Show us an Ajax request to main_d.php where you try to get a get variable, which you have in a a href that Points to info.hmtl ? I have honestly no idea what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax only posts to your PHP file. you only send the POST-variable "type" to your script. if you really want to post the variable "type" and send the GET-variable "id", you can do this (not recommended):

```
var your_id = 4; // use your dynamic id value here
$.ajax ({
    method: "POST",
    url:"main_d.php?id=" + your_id,
    data: {type : 4}
})
.done(function(msg_info) {
    $('#info_id').append(msg_info)
})
```

Comment: or you also post the id: `data: {type : 4, id: 12}`

Comment: @MartinGottweis yes - or you could also use `$_REQUEST["var_name"]` in your PHP which resolves both, GET and POST vars.

Comment: @FoxWizzy then insert it to the ajax script with php